# Datatables edit a column not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

am a newbie to jEditable with datatables...

I am generating a table and trying to edit a column, here is the code right after the dynamic html..,

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        $('td:eq(4)', this.fnGetNodes()).editable('<url>', {
            "callback": function(sValue, y) {
                var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
            },
            "height": "14px",
            "tooltip": 'Click to edit...'
        });
    }
});
```

Can anybody explain the code inside "callback" and "submitdata"

**EDIT**:
How to do prior validation before POSTing the value? should I submit to a function, can anybody give me an example...

Comment: You definitely only need one copy of your initialization object. Having it in the document ready is reasonable. Delete the other copy.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to have the code twice?

Answer (score 0):

In [jEditable documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), it explains `callback` as:

> (Function) **callback**: Function is called after form has been submitted.
>   Callback function receives two parameters. Value contains submitted
>   form content. Settings contain all plugin settings. Inside function
>   this refers to the original element.

It is called after the response is received from the data submission to the `url` specified in the first parameter of `.editable()`. In your case, `oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1])` would be called after the response is got back from data submission, to update the appropriate cell with the new value.

As for `submitdata`:

> (Mixed) **submitdata**: Extra parameters when submitting content. Can be
>   either a hash or function returning a hash.

By default, jEditable POSTs two sets of data to the url: `id` (ID of the editable element) and `value` (entered value). `submitdata` allows you to add extra parameters to the POST data.

So, originally the data is sent as:

`id=cell_id&value=edited_content`

In your case, the data would look like this:

`id=cell_id&value=edited_content&row_id=tr_id&column=column_index`

Comment: I hope my explanation helps you identify the culprit. If not, please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I still can't figure out, how this explanation fits into what I am trying to do: Simply put, I am editing a column, the url returns "yes" or "no"(If validation errors occur).., I am having difficulty realizing this...

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Comment: Hi William, can you explain how to do validation on the "value" prior to doing the POST?

Comment: That's a different question; you should post a new question for it.

Comment: did you end up solving the question you originally asked?

Comment: Hi William, I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930084/jeditable-datatables-validate-value-before-posting