# jeditable-datatables , validate "value" before posting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to use jEditable with Datatables. How to go about validating the input "value" before POSTing:

Here is the code am using

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable( {         
    "fnDrawCallback": function(){
        $('td:eq(4)', this.fnGetNodes()).editable('<url>',  {
                "callback": function(sValue, y) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
            oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
        }
    });
     }  
});
```

**EDIT** where should the validation code go? before

`$('td:eq(4)', this.fnGetNodes()).editable('<url>',  {`

or before

```
oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
```

Comment: do you need to validate whether it's null or not?

Comment: I have to do more than that, I already have the validation code as I am using that logic in a different page, validation includes making couple AJAX calls to query against database.

Comment: so you already have a function that does validation? does it return a boolean value? if so, just use if statement checking for that returning value

Comment: Where should I use this if statement? Because the validation has to occur only when the user hits the enter key inside the cell

Comment: try to use it before the oTable.fnUpdate...try `if (validate_value(sValue)) {oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]); }`

Comment: But at that point the POST request was already being made? I have to validate first and then make the POST request.., am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, I am assuming you want to validate the value before updating the table? if so, that's where you should place that

Comment: I want to validate before I make the post request that is before            $('td:eq(4)', this.fnGetNodes()).editable('<url>', {   , But if I do so, the validation is happening right when the datatables is initialized.., anybody has a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the validations at the server by sending additional required URL parameters using the "submitdata" option.

Comment: What do you do on server side for null URL values ?